# Is there a way to keep menus from closing?

Tags: interface

Is there a way to keep menus from closing when my cursor isn't on it? I use screen magnification and I often inevitably "fall off" menus. So frustrating.

I'm a newbie, by the way.

Comment: This is not usually a problem for most users. Could you provide more context about why you use magnification and how? Is it possible to make a [gif](https://www.screentogif.com/) or record the screen with the problem happening? It is usual to first select something in Blender and then use some operation that does something to the selection, so there is usually no reason to move the mouse away from menus or look around with magnification when you are choosing something from a menu. It might help to set(or use existing) hotkeys for menus you use often, or add stuff to quick favourites menu...

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: No, there is no way to keep menus from closing when you move the mouse away. This is not exposed in the user preferences in any way:

[image]

These are all the settings available for menus. If you described your use case in more detail it may be possible to find some workaround to make it more convenient though.

Blender is famous for its keyboard hotkeys. There are a lot of them. And you can also set them for most things like the menus. If you use hotkeys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for *Vertex*, *Edge*, *Face* menus while modelling in *Edit Mode*, those menus appear at the mouse position in 3d viewport:

[image]

You can set hotkeys for menus, but that's a bit tricky, because you have to create the hotkeys manually(as opposed to just right-clicking and choosing "Assign Shortcut" for operators). If that's something that may be helpful to you, just ask a new question about setting hotkeys for a menu.

Comment: The reason i use screen magnification is because I'm VI--visually impaired. My eyes are a foot or less away from my screen and using magnification means i can only see about 1/4 of the screen at a time. Windows's built-in is similar to what i use. Set it to 600% and you have the equivalent of my screen.

i know, it's not very common for VI people to do digital arts, but i have for the past decade or so. i just haven't invested much time in Blender because of the issue with the menus. it's like the only program i know that auto-closes menus when your cursor isn't on it.

Comment: "Set it to 600% and you have the equivalent of my screen." What's the size and resolution of your screen?

Comment: 27" screen at 1920 x 1200 resolution

Comment: I still fail to replicate the issue with menus to be honest. When I try to see them, the mouse is on them so they don't disappear, when I try to see something else, I don't need the menus.

Comment: I just ran into this myself. Blender's menu implementation differs from macOS menu bars (and I think also Windows). Normally, moving the cursor away from a standard menu does not close it. Your cursor can move anywhere on screen and the menu will remain open. It will only close if you click. I don't see any advantage to this design, it seems to be a mistake.

Comment: No mistake. The menus disappear when the cursor is certain distance away. Blender's UI philosophy is for it to be non-blocking. This is in line with it. That's why it's all one window and no floating child windows. It works as intended to reduce distractions and need to manage things that hide other things. ...in most cases. A bigger monitor would probably help, or some other system of magnification maybe... I am not sure I understand how this issue works. I seem to be able to use the menus with magnification fine as I don't see any need to move the mouse away while navigating menus...