# Prevent context-menus from automatically closing

Tags: interface

I'm new to Blender. I'm using the current version (3.6.1). I have some physical deficiencies (sub-par eyesight) as well as cognitive (ADD).

I've noticed that context menus, and some other pop-ups like color wheels, are closed automatically when the mouse is moved away some distance. That makes it very hard for me to use these UI elements.

I use the mouse cursor extensively to guide my focus, that could mean following entries in a menu with my cursor while reading though the entires, but also moving the cursor somewhere else on the screen, out of my sight, so it won't distract me by pointing at a random location I don't actually want to focus on. This is a habit that I have built over the last 25 years and helps me a lot in using complex software. So I imagine that trying to get rid of that habit within a single application will be near-impossible in the short term for me, and would also be detrimental to my ability to comprehend the UI.

Is there anything I can do about it in the current version of Blender? For example, can I change the distance at which these UI elements are closed automatically (so I could set it to practically infinity)?

Comment: I don't think there's a setting to change this and any discussion about it would be off topic here, but it might be worth raising it on the [Developer Forum](https://devtalk.blender.org/) as there was a brief thread about it [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/tablets-and-popup-menu-auto-closing-on-mouse-distance/15735) a couple of years ago. There's also [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293869/is-there-a-way-to-keep-menus-from-closing?rq=1) posting about it here from a couple of months ago.